# Updating an analog clock appwidget

Tags: android, android-widget

I am looking for a way to update a custom analogue clock every minute as a homescreen widget.

The built in AnalogClock widget was deprecated. The minimum interval for a JobScheduler is 15 minutes, and may not run at all on some devices that have OEM background restrictions. A foreground service seems like the only option.

However, [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.style_7.analogclockwidgetplussize_7) and many others have custom watch faces, which are probably bitmaps in an ImageView, and shows the correct time, without creating a foreground service.

How do they manage to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got impatient and decompiled the app. They still use `AnalogClock` and it seems to work and self update, even though it is deprecated since API 23 and Google has stated "This widget is no longer supported." in the docs. The custom faces and hands are drawables set on the AnalogClock. There are no ImageViews involved (at least for what I saw)